# Upgrading to Firebase Crashlytics

Tags: android, firebase, crashlytics

I have followed the steps on [this](https://firebase.google.com/docs/crashlytics/upgrade-sdk?authuser=0&platform=android) firebase crashlytics upgrade guide and I have replaced all the code for recording crashes in my app. But I am still getting a warning in the firebase console that says "Please upgrade to the generally available Firebase Crashlytics SDK to continue receiving crash reports in the Firebase console after 15 November 2020".
Is there another step that I should do to upgrade.
I am also still receiving crashes from older versions of my app that are not upgraded to the newest SDK. Could this be why the warning is popping up on firebase?

Comment: This message is visible to everyone. Even to projects that are using the new version since day 1.

Comment: If you have problems or questions about the Firebase console, contact Firebase support for assistance.  https://support.google.com/firebase/contact/support

Comment: Same problem here.
"The following project(s) linked with your account include apps that have enabled Crashlytics and not adopted the new SDKs:"
And the following projects are already up to date.

Answer (score 0):

After [upgrade](https://firebase.google.com/docs/crashlytics/upgrade-sdk?authuser=0&platform=android) firebase libraries:

---

### **Test your Crashlytics implementation**

[Force a crash to test your implementation](https://firebase.google.com/docs/crashlytics/test-implementation?authuser=0&platform=android)

```
val crashButton = Button(this)
crashButton.text = "Crash!"
crashButton.setOnClickListener {
   throw RuntimeException("Test Crash") // Force a crash
}

addContentView(crashButton, ViewGroup.LayoutParams(
       ViewGroup.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT,
       ViewGroup.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT))
```

### **Enable Crashlytics debug logging**

```
adb shell setprop log.tag.FirebaseCrashlytics DEBUG
```

> instead of enabling debug logging you can build a release version and Force a crash in the release apk to test your Crashlytics implementation
> crash

---

**After your Forced crash in release version, this message should be displayed in the firebase console**

[image: You have the latest SDK installed]

> It may take up to five minutes for the report to appear in the
> Firebase console

Comment: where in the firebase console does the message appear?

Comment: The message is displayed on the Crashlytics page(firebase console) instead of the message "Please upgrade to the Firebase Crashlytics SDK by 15 November 2020 to continue getting crash reports"

Answer (score -1):

My application was using fabric. I was getting continuous message to upgrade to sdk before 15Nov 2020.
I followed same link
https://firebase.google.com/docs/crashlytics/upgrade-sdk?platform=android.

After 4-5 hours releasing it to my testing team. Firebase console updated to notify me that application is using latest sdk.

Step 1: Go to firebase console.
Step 2: select your project.
Step 3: Go to Crashlytics option from left menu.
STep4: you will get below page.

[image]